# How to check if the data has been saved to coredata in swift?

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-data, view

There's a coredata entity named `Profile` and it has an attribute called `userName`. We save it to coredata using the following code. This file is named `ProfileEditView`

```
import SwiftUI

struct ProfileEditView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    
    @State private var userName = ""
    
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Enter your details")) {
                    TextField("UserName", text: $userName)
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Add you details")
            .toolbar {
                Button("Save") {
                    
                    let profile = Profile(context: moc)
                    profile.userName = userName
                    
                    try? moc.save()
                    dismiss()
                    
                }
                .disabled(checkDisableForm)
            }
        }
    }
    
    var checkDisableForm: Bool {
        if (checkEmpty() == false) {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
    
    
    func checkEmpty() -> Bool {
        if userName.isEmpty{
            return false
        }
        else {
            return true
        }
    }
}

struct ProfileView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ProfileEditView()
    }
}
```

It creates a form and when I enter the userName and hit save, it works as expected. In another view, I try to fetch and print the name on the screen, but it never prints. This is what the code looks like. This file is named `ReviewView`.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ReviewView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: []) var profileInfo: FetchedResults<Profile>
        
    var body: some View {
        Text("Lamo Kera")  // This line prints on the screen
        List(profileInfo){ pInfo in
            Text(pInfo.race ?? "Unknown") // But this line doesn't
        }
    }
}


struct ReviewView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ReviewView()
    }
}
```

The code for both of the views look fine to me. My two questions:
i) What am I missing here?
ii) How do I check if coredata has saved the data? Is it possible to do it using DB browser for sqlite?

Comment: If you are concerned if saving works then you shouldn’t use `try?` when calling `save()`. Handle the error instead by using `try` and at least print/log any errors thrown. And yes you can use that app for checking your SQLite database.

Comment: I used try catch, and turns out the data isn't being saved to coredata. It's throwing "nilError". I am trying to undestand why. Thanks

Comment: 1) What is your problem? 2 I check my database using [DB Browser for SQLite](https://sqlitebrowser.org).

Comment: My problem was that I didn't know how to check whether my data was saved to coredata. Thanks to Joakim that I am able to figure it out now using try/catch. But I also want to be able to check the same thing in DB Browser for sqlite. Do I need to connect the DB with coredata? I have downloaded the DB but I haven't found a proper tutorial to guide me through it @Reinhard Männer. Thanks